# How to display an image using tkinter in Python?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image

    top = Tk()

    file ='flame2.jpg'
    filename = PhotoImage(file)

    panel=PanedWindow()
    panel = Label(top, image = filename)

    panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand= "yes")
    top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [PIL](https://askubuntu.com/questions/156484/how-do-i-install-python-imaging-library-pil/596516) to read such complicated image formats and pass them as *understandable* objects to tkinter:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
...
my_image = Image.open("flame2.jpg")
filename= ImageTk.PhotoImage(my_image)
...
panel = Label(top, image=filename)
```

Comment: my_image = Image.open("flame2.jpg")
AttributeError: type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'

After compiling the code you sent, this is the error occured.

Comment: Try `import PIL.Image` instead of `from PIL import Image`

Comment: Error remains the same.